# Strip dirty HTML text not inside HTML tags Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a weird situation where some text got inserted into a JSON html parse and it is not inside HTML tags. I want to just remove the text all together. I have tried some regex but couldnt get it to quite work. The text looks like this:

```
<span>-$45.00</span>Discount (testdev)<span>Subtotal</span>
```

I want to remove the "Discount (testdev)". It seems easy but the "testdev" is dynamic so I cant just do a string replace on that. Thanks.

Comment: is this the whole string?

Comment: one useful link I like to use is [this](https://regex101.com/#javascript)

Comment: @ZergRush you cannot parse arbitrary HTML with regex.

Comment: Do you know that there will always be exactly one span on each side of the text? Also, show us the regex you have tried.

Comment: I would always suggest that you avoid parsing arbitrary HTML with regular expressions, and instead use the DOM to remove 'unwrapped' text, for example: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q5au4u20/).

Comment: sorry thought he had the string before it got to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
str = "<span>-$45.00</span>Discount (testdev)<span>Subtotal</span>";

console.log(str.replace(/(<\/span>)(Discount.*?)(<span>)/, removeStr))

function removeStr(str, before, removed, after) {
  return before + after;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I didnt realize you could put in a wildcard like that.